# Derivative of Kronecker products

Tags: calculus, hilbert-spaces

I would like to calculate the derivative of a function of a tensor product:

$$\frac{d(a\otimes a'(t))}{dt}$$

where the $a$'s are density matrices. Can someone please provide the rules for taking derivatives of such things? Can they be broken down into separate parts?

Answer (score 1):

The map $(a,a') \mapsto a\otimes a'$ is bilinear, so the product rule applies (we're also using a chain rule since we're making $a$ and $a'$ depend on $t$ --- I'm also assuming, from your use of notation, that $a'$ does not stand for the derivative of $a$): $$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} (a\otimes a')(t) =\left( \frac{{\rm d}a}{{\rm d}t} \otimes a'\right)(t)+\left(a \otimes \frac{{\rm d}a'}{{\rm d}t}\right)(t).$$